# Creating new observations in pytorch ImageFolder

Tags: python, machine-learning, pytorch, image-recognition

I am new to pythorch and what I would like to do will probably be easy, but I have not found anything online regarding actually increasing the number of observations without adding them into the image (in my case) folder. I don't want to add images to the folder because I want to play around with different transformations and see what is best without deleting images all the time. So what I do is:

```py
trf = transforms.Compose([
    transforms.ToTensor(),
    transforms.RandomRotation(degrees=45),
    transforms.Grayscale(num_output_channels=1),
    transforms.Normalize(0, 1),
    transforms.functional.invert
])
train_data = torchvision.datasets.ImageFolder(root='./splitted_data/train', transform= trf)
print(len(train_data))
train = DataLoader(train_data, batch_size= batch_size, shuffle= True,  num_workers= os.cpu_count())
```

Here the output will be the same as the number of images in all folders, which means that transformations were applied to the existing observations, but this is not something that I want to achieve. I want each transformation to be a separate copy. How can I do that?

Comment: What do you mean exactly by *separate copy*?

Comment: @Ivan Say I have one observation. I want to apply grayscale and random rotation to it. The output should be 1. The original image 2. grayscaled image 3. rotated image 4. grayscaled rotated (not necessary, the first 3 is ok). So we now have 3 (4) observations instead of 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can implement a transform wrapper that will apply transforms sequentially and output every single transform combination. The issue with Torchvision's random transform is that the parameters are sampled when the transform is called. This makes it difficult to reproduce identical transformations. One alternative is to stack or concatenate all the images and apply the transform once on that stack.

I divided the transformation pipeline in three sections: the preprocessing and post-processing transform (*the latter should not be stochastic* since it is applied separately).  As for the main transforms, they are the list of transforms you want to create combinations from, here `RandomRotation` and `Grayscale`.

Be aware, this solution has limitations when working with transforms that affect the channel number such as Grayscale. Generally, you want to keep the same tensor dimensions otherwise your concatenations and/or stacks will fail.

Here is a possible solution:

```
class Combination(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, transforms, pre, post):
        super().__init__()
        self.transforms = transforms
        self.pre = T.Compose(pre)
        self.post = T.Compose(post)

    def stacked_t(self, t, x):
        lengths = [len(o) for o in x]
        return t(torch.cat(x)).split(lengths)

    def forward(self, x):
        out = [self.pre(x)[None]]
        for t in transforms:
            out += self.stacked_t(t, out) # <- for every transform `t` we double
                                          #    the number of instances in` out`
        out = [self.post(o)[0] for o in out]
        return out
```

Here is an example usage with an input image:

```
>>> img
```

[image]

Initialize the transform combination:

```
>>> t = Combination(pre=[T.ToTensor()],
...                 post=[T.Normalize(0, 1),
...                       T.functional.invert],
...                 transforms=[T.RandomRotation(degrees=45),
...                             T.Grayscale(num_output_channels=1)])
```

Here is a preview of the different transform combinations:

```
>>> img_ = t(img)
```

| `img_[0]` | `img_[1]` | `img_[2]` | `img_[3]` |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| [image] | [image] | [image] | [image] |

Comment: This is great! But how do I create a dataloader object out of this? Because if I try using this just like I did ```trf```, it is still the same size.

Comment: *"still the same size"*, there is no resize transform, what do you mean?

Comment: I meant the dataset size. I still get the same amount of pictures after doing the transformations.

Comment: What is the shape of one batch tensor?

Comment: I believe it doesn't really matter since I am talking about the dataset first of all, not dataloader, but I am planning to use is 10 images per batch. The size that I want to increase is ```len(train_data)``` in my question.

Comment: Have you tried using the transform shown above and plugged it into a dataloader? If so - and that was my initial question - can you tell me the shape of a batch?

Comment: I have plugged it in ```ImageFolder``` just like the old transformation. dataloader has no attribute ```transform``` did you mean ```collate_fn```? The shape of a batch is 10, however, it is irrelevant if we are talking about ```ImageFolder```. If you want me to pass it to the dataloader somehow, the batch size is 10.

Comment: Can you give the *complete* shape of one batch?